I don't get the proof of kernel and image subspaces here
https://ibb.co/xGVsqsW
Why is ker(T) a subspace of V and im(T) a subspace is W? It looks like they are both a subspace of V because they found T(av1+bv2) both times.
Basically, it finds T(av1+bv2) for im(T) and ker(T). How is that related to subspace V or subspace W?
Link to the textbook page:
https://math.libretexts.org/Courses/Lake_Tahoe_Community_College/A_First_Course_in_Linear_Algebra_(Kuttler)/05%3A_Linear_Transformations/5.07%3A_The_Kernel_and_Image_of_A_Linear_Map

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Please do not rely on images to convey the question. Write it using MathJax.

The kernel is a subspace of the domain because it is a subset of the domain and it satisfies the definition of a subspace. The image is a subspace of the codomain because it is a subset of the codomain and it satisfies the definition of subspace. Do you know the definition of subspace? Do you understand that the image of any function whatsoever is a subset of the codomain?

Are you taking a class? If so, I think it would be best if you asked a professor, TA, or classmate in person.

@Deane I'll try next time - though it's interesting that Stack Exchange might be faster because often questions get answered in less than 20 minutes. I'm in an asynchronous class too

Anything to say about the answers that have been posted, ddo? or, the comments?

The definition of the kernel of a linear transformation is the set of all vectors in $V$ that $T$ maps to the zero vector in $W$, or in other words:
\begin{align*}
    \text{ker}(T) = \left\{ v \in V | T(v) = 0 \right\}
\end{align*}
To show this is a subspace of V we verify the usual conditions of a subspace. The zero element is just shown by $T(0) = 0$ (the zero vector of $V$ is mapped to the zero vector of $W$), so we have $0 \in \text{ker}(T)$. Closure under addition and scalar multiplcation follows similar ideas:
Take $v_1, v_2 \in \text{ker}(T)$. From our definition of the kernel, this means that $T(v_1) = 0, T(v_2) = 0$. Because $T$ is linear we can compose them together: $T(v_1 + v_2) = T(v_1) + T(v_2) = 0 + 0 = 0$. Again, this is the same form as our definition of the kernel, so we can say $v_1 + v_2 \in \text{ker}(T)$.
For scalar multiplication: if $v \in \text{ker}(T)$ and $c$ is a scalar value, then $T(cv) = cT(v)$ (by linearity), $= c(0) = 0 \in \text{ker}(T)$. Thus, we have met the criteria for the kernel of $T$ to be a subspace of $V$.
Now for the image of T we're looking for something slightly different. The definition here is the set of vectors in $W$ that can be expressed as $T(v),\hspace{0.1cm} v \in V$ in some way. In other words:
\begin{align*}
    \text{im}(T) = \left\{ w \in W | w = T(v) \hspace{0.2cm} \text{for some} \hspace{0.2cm} v \in V \right\}
\end{align*}
For the zero element, we know $T(0) = 0$ already, so clearly $0$ can be expressed in our required form, and so we're set there.
Now for addition: take $w_1, w_2 \in \text{im}(T)$. We can say then that $w_1 = T(v_1), w_2 = T(v_2)$ for some $v_1, v_2 \in V$. Using linearity we can write then: $w_1 + w_2 = T(v_1) + T(v_2) = T(v_1 + v_2)$, which again is the form we need, so we know that $w_1 + w_2 \in \text{im}(T)$.
Lastly, scalar multiplication: take $w \in W$ and $c$ some scalar. Then $cw = cT(v) = T(cv)$, and we can then conclude that $cw \in \text{im}(T)$. Therefore, im$(T)$ is a subspace of $W$.
Quick recap: it's easy for me to think about the kernel mapping to V because we're talking about where vectors begin in $V$. For the image, we looked at where things ended up, so we turned to $W$ instead. I hope this helps :)

If we consider a linear transformation $T:V \rightarrow W $ by definition $Ker(T)= \{x \in V \ / \ T(x)=O  \} \Rightarrow Ker (T) \subseteq V $ and is linear space too, can be demonstrated, then is  lineal subespace of V. By definition $Im(T)= \{ T(x) \ / x \in V \} $ but $ T(x) \in W $ then $ Im(T) \subseteq W $ and is linear space too, can be demonstrated, then is  lineal subespace of W, by definition of lineal subespace.
.
